# force low graphics mode in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

how to force ubuntu 11.04 to run on low graphics mode ? ( sorry if I posted in a wrong section ) 
I'm using a p4 machine and xserver stucks at a certain point in everytime , but it's running fine with low graphics mode, since I only do programming stuff , I don't need effects any way ( btw disabling effects at startup doesn't worked either ) 
but when I start the machine , only sometimes it's asked to run in low graphics mode ,

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). If you have more questions similar to this, you might want to post them on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out , all I hv to do is , start ubuntu with recovery mode and then select low graphics mode !, any way I think no need of changing the GRUB ...and ubuntu 11.04 not supporting #ATI radeon x300